# How to have different time in cv2.waitkey for 2 windows in webcam

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Well I am beginner in OpenCV. I have 2 windows of webcam; one of them should run normally (i.e `cv2.waitkey(1)`) and the other should run after each one second (i.e `cv2.waitkey(1000)`).

How can I do it?

Comment: use a gui framework with  such kind of features like Qt

Comment: well I don't know what is a gui framework, how to install and what are those features

Comment: Update the second window less frequently than the first one... assuming your main can run at 1000Hz (which it won't, but let's ignore that), you'd then only update the second windows once in 1000 iterations.

Comment: Dan I am not able to understand what you are saying

Comment: What Dan is saying is this. You seem to want one window updated every 1millisecond and the other updated every 1second. So call `imshow()` for the faster updating window contents on every iteration through your loop followed by `waitkey(1)` and your faster updating window is sorted out. Then call `imshow()` to update the slower window contents just once for every 1,000 passes through the loop, so it will get updated less frequently.